# LibGDX if 2 objects touches, do something

Tags: java, object, libgdx, touch, contains

i have been testing to create a function which would do something, if two objects touch(if one contains or it is just touching the another one). I found this:

```
public boolean inBounds(float cx, float cy, int size)
    {
        Rectangle rec1 = new Rectangle(x, y, this.size, this.size);
        Rectangle rec2 = new Rectangle(cx, cy, size, size);

            if(rec1.contains(rec2)) return true;

        return false;
    }
    }
```

So, this is a touch function in my Entity class. So, in my update function which i am calling in render function, i have:

```
if (e instanceof Worm && player1.inBounds(e.x, e.y, e.size))  
            {
                entities.remove(i); //remove object from the scene
                i--;
                player1.incScore(); //increase score
            }
```

This works perfectly, but only if my charracter is biger than that object, i need it everytime, no only if charracter is biger than object. So what to do now? i Found a function that i can use like `if (rec1.overlaps(rec2)) return true;` but now, it works, yes.. but the texture of my object is not so ultimate(this is the object: http://img24.cz/images/08705660216361901876.png ), so it looks bad. if the object is near the player, it activates my function, i want to have it only if the object is in the player, so i can create better texture, which is really hard for me, or i can ... I dont know what i can to do, so, help me please. :D

Comment: Make a new rectangle smaller than your player and put in the middle of the player. Check if fish overlaps with that rectangle. As a result the fish will go further inside the player until it touches the inner rectangle and then your function will be triggered, causing to have the behaviour you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, Thats good, i tried it, it actually works. ;) :D Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.

First.
Use temporary rectangles, don't create new one every frame!

You are checking rectangle.contains(otherRectangle); which tells you if otherRectangle is inside the rectangle.
You want to check if the rectangle **overlaps** the other one.

```
private Rectangle tmpRect1=new Rectangle();
private Rectangle tmpRect2=new Rectangle();
```

And in your method

```
public boolean inBounds(float cx, float cy, int size)
    {
        tmpRect1.set(x, y, this.size, this.size);
        tmpRect2.set(cx, cy, size, size);

        return tmpRect1.overlaps(tmpRect2); // returns true if rectangles are overlapping, and false if not

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but it doesnt fix my problem. my problem was that, that if i am using the overlaps function, it looks unreal. Because(look at http://img24.cz/images/08705660216361901876.png ), you can see that the top of the image is clean, there is not my fish, my fish is only in the middle of image, so it looks bad, if the player is under or over the fish, it gives me a score(because it is overlapping(because of that non-ultimate image)). The contain function was better, because it looked reallistic. So i wanted a help, how do i can make it better.